# Can Sphinx napoleon document function returning multiple arguments?

Tags: python, python-sphinx, sphinx-napoleon

I am trying to use the Google code style to document a function that I then use sphinx with the napoleon extension to create documentation for. The function is unusual in that is returns two arguments. I don't think napoleon handles this. If so, could someone tell me how they handle it?

```
def foo(a):
'''one line summary

longer explanation

Args:
  a (int): parameter description

Returns:
  servers (list): list of servers to use
  msg (str): logging message string 
'''
pass
```

Maybe I'm getting a message that it is not great coding style to return multiple arguments, but can you do this? The html generated treats those two lines as part of a description for one argument. If I put a newline between the servers and msg line, it helps, but it is still documenting one arg.

Comment: Related issue: [Using multiple return values in Google-style docstrings #9119](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9119)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Python only returns a single object. If you call

```
serv,msg = foo(myinput)
```

Then you are explicitly expanding the expression_list tuple which is generated when the function returns with this code

```
return servers,msg
```

You docstring should read some thing like this (with the Napoleon Google Style)

```
"""
one line summary

longer explanation

Args:
    a (int): parameter description

Returns:
    (tuple): tuple containing:

        servers(list) servers to use
        msg (str): logging message string 
"""
```

Or with the Napoleon NumPy style:

```
"""
one line summary

longer explanation

Parameters
----------
a : int
    parameter description

Returns
-------
servers : list
    servers to use
msg : str
    logging message string 
"""
```

Have a look at the python docs for [return](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-return-statement) and perhaps [expression_list](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists)

Comment: I am not sure if that's what the OP is referring to, but what if you have a function like `if foo: return foo else: return bar`?

Comment: yeah its ambiguous. the OP should post some code to make it clear

Comment: Thanks! That is what I'm looking for, and it makes sense, it is probably good to document the return type as tuple rather than jumping right into a description of the tuple elements like I thought I could, but I couldn't quite get it to work (I have very little experience with sphinx at present). The two lines that describe servers and msg do start on a newly indented line, but there is no parsing of the lines, they are treated as one paragraph. Can I get sphinx/napoleon to introduce the same kind of formatting it applies to Args parameters to the tuple elements?

Comment: You might need an extra line in between; I've updated the example above. I'm not using the google style. I know that the Numpy Style does support multiple return values. Checkout http://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html#google-vs-numpy

Comment: Looks like Google style won't support multiple return values: https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx-contrib/issues/111/napoleon-multiple-returns-indentations

Comment: @MrCartoonology I use a dash before each of the tuple elements to turn them into a bullet-pointed list.  In the ReadTheDocs style I'm using, they now look similar to the arguments.

Answer (score 20):

Google style does not support multiple return values. As a workaround you can use:

```
Returns:
    2-element tuple containing

    - **rates** (*array*): the unnormalized rates (just the sum of the
      exponential kernels). To obtain rates in Hz divide the
      array by `2*tau` (or other conventional `x*tau` duration).
    - **nph** (*array*): number of photons in -5*tau..5*tau window
      for each timestamp. Proportional to the rate computed
      with KDE and rectangular kernel.
```

This results in a nice output even with multi-line description for each returned item.

Comment: Do you think aliasing Returns to Args is a better idea for this purpose? https://sphinxcontrib-napoleon.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sphinxcontrib.napoleon.html#sphinxcontrib.napoleon.Config.napoleon_custom_sections

Comment: @SibbsGambling No, because then the extra values  would be merged into the existing Parameters.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure napoleon to interpret the `Returns` section of a Google-style docstring like the `Args` section using the [`napoleon_custom_sections`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/napoleon.html#confval-napoleon_custom_sections) setting.

```
napoleon_custom_sections = [('Returns', 'params_style')]
```

This way, multiple return values (as given in the question) are rendered nicely by Sphinx. However, I am not entirely sure if one is still strictly adhering to the Google-style docstring convention when using this option.

Answer (score 0):

After trying several options, this format worked for me

```py
def foo(a):
    """
    
    Args:
        a (int): parameter description

    Returns:
        - list: 
          parameter description
        - str: 
          logging message string
    """
```

Note the two spaces after the linebreak.