# Sphinx Napoleon Extension: document multiple return arguments with Google Style docstrings

Tags: python, python-sphinx, google-style-guide, sphinx-napoleon

This question is related to [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29343326/1334711). The proposed and accepted solution is:

```
Returns:
       (tuple): tuple containing:                        
                    arg1: First Argument
                    arg2: Second Argument
```

This solution is not working, at least for me. The indented sub-block with `arg1` and `arg2` description is not parsed.

How should I manage multiple returns with `sphinx`, `sphinx.ext.napoleon` and Google Style docstring?

Comment: I think that it's a duplicate of this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221551/can-sphinx-napoleon-document-function-returning-multiple-arguments).

Comment: For posterity, the second, unaccepted answer on the other thread works fine.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue that [won't be fixed](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues/9119) by the sphinx project (current maintainers of `napoleon`). As mentioned at the link, they don't consider multi-line returns a part of google spec and won't fix this.

Comment: updated the above to point to issue in sphinx repo. they won't fix this

Answer (score 0):

Try to use use the newline character `\n` in your docstring:

```
Returns:
    tuple: tuple containing:

        servers (list): servers to use \n
        msg (str): logging message string
```