# How to denote return type tuple in Google-style Pydoc for Pycharm?

Tags: python, pycharm, pydoc

In Pycharm I want to have a documented function that returns a tuple so that I can get code completion on it. The style of comments is Google-style.

---

This **works** correctly:

```
def func():
    """

    Returns:
        str: something

    """
    pass
```

Typing `func().` correctly shows methods for `str`.

---

However, typing this **does not** work anymore:

```
def func():
    """

    Returns:
        (int, str): something

    """
    pass

a, b = func()
```

Typing `b.` does not offer anything.

---

I know that PyCharm is capable of parsing tuples, because this code **works**:

```
def func():
    """

    :rtype: (int, str)
    """
    pass

a, b = func()
```

However, this is not according to the Google style.

---

How do I document a function according to the standard so that Pycharm will pick up on the return types?

Comment: Well, quoting an answer and a comment from https://stackoverflow.com/q/29221551/8516269 , it seems that the "Google style does not support multiple return values".

So how would a return type according to the Google style standard look like in the first place?

Answer (score 5):

Here is how I'd do it:

```
from typing import Tuple

def func() -> Tuple[int, str]:
    """ (...)

    Returns:
        A tuple containing, respectively, an int (<meaning of the
        returned int>) and a string (<meaning of the returned string>).
    """
```

PyCharm (and Sphinx, if you're using it to parse your docstrings) will correctly know the return type of your function and you'll have a clean and nice description of the function's return value.

Answer (score 2):

Would the type hints as specified by PEP 484 not be valid?

[Python 3 docs for typing module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html)

[Python PEP 484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/)

```
from typing import Tuple

def func():
    """

    :rtype: Tuple[int, str]
    """
    pass

a, b = func()
```

Answer (score 0):

from doc pages of sphinxcontrib

> The `Returns` section supports any reStructuredText formatting,
>   including literal blocks::
>
> ```
>         {
>             'param1': param1,
>             'param2': param2
>         }
> ```
>
> [Documentation](https://gist.github.com/dsaiztc/9b4c15c6dfef08a957c1)

this says that Google style supports the reStructuredText formatting inside, and using below format returns me the tuple autocomplete options.

```
def func():
    """

    Returns:
        :rtype: (int, str)

    """
    pass

a, b = func()
```

can this be the solution you were looking for?

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to achieve auto-completion in PyCharm I would suggest using type hinting on the function definition (`Tuple[int, str]`).

```py
from typing import Tuple

def func() -> Tuple[int, str]:
    """

    :rtype: (int, str)
    """
    pass

a, b = func()
```

I know your question is about how to achieve this through the docstring, but my strong recommendation is to make use of type hinting since it will allow tools like mypy to validate your code (something that can't be done with docstrings - [Can mypy check docstrings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53221369/can-mypy-check-docstrings)).

I am not saying you shouldn't also include types in docstrings, just that your IDE is more likely to support static type hinting, and static type hinting allows you to use a greater degree of granularity in your definitions.