# Can mypy check docstrings?

Tags: python, mypy, numpydoc

I have [numpydoc-style docstrings](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html):

```
def foobar(filename, copy, dtype, iterable, shape, files):
    """
    foobar is 42.

    Parameters
    ----------
    filename : str
    copy : bool
    dtype : data-type
    iterable : iterable object
    shape : int or tuple of int
    files : list of str

    Returns
    -------
    foobarfoo : int
    """
    pass
```

**Is it possible to check if the docstring-types can possibly be correct?**

(side question: Can numpy return/print the function signatures it discovered?)

For example, I would expect the following to fail:

### Return Types

```
def foobar():
    """
    Returns
    -------
    blub : int
    """
    return "foo"
```

or

```
def foobar(a, b):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    a : number
    b : number

    Returns
    -------
    blub : int
    """
    if a > b:
        return "foo"
    return 42
```

### Parameter types

```
def foobar(a, b):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    a : str
    b : int

    Returns
    -------
    blub : int
    """
    return a * b
```

Answer (score 3):

No, mypy understands the official Python's typing notation only. See [the mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cheat_sheet_py3.html#cheat-sheet-py3). And this fine, we don't need many alternative ways to type annotate, as

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Comment: Aparently you got me wrong. I don't want mypy to assume the docstring is correct. I want to check the docstring correctnes with mypy. As to your comment about "only one way to do it": Can mypy generate documentation?

Comment: @MartinThoma I think I understood you correctly, after all, because my reply is the answer to "I want to check the docstring correctnes with mypy." problem as well :) So, mypy does not analyze docstrings at all, in any way. It uses Python's type annotations and the very code to get (or guess) types and analyze them. As far as I know, docstrings are *completely ignored* by mypy.

Comment: This is not exactly true. Mypy understands and parses docstrings as defined in PEP484. See the following link: https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python2.html

Comment: @ZoranPavlovic Could you quote the relevant parts of PEP 484 and docs you've linked to? I cannot find there anything about mypy understanding and parsing docstrings, but I may be missing something.

Comment: Heading. Type checking Python 2 code:
For code that needs to be Python 2.7 compatible, function type annotations are given in comments, since the function annotation syntax was introduced in Python 3.