# reStructuredText with newlines on return statement

Tags: python, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I'm getting a bit crazy on a problem which is fairly simple.

I'm using Python with *PyCharm* and reStructuredText for docstring. Sometimes, my functions might return several values. I indent them with new lines but when seeing the docstring in *PyCharm* there aren't any. I've tried a bunch of things like \n, \br, making a list (-) but didn't find a working solution.

Edit : adding code example

```
def to_min_max(self) -> (np.ndarray, np.ndarray):
    """
    Searches the min and max positive values per every main features. Ie. the min and max for E0, E1, E2
    (resp. Phi0, Phi1, Phi2, etc.) are the same.

    The negative values are ignored during the search.

    The returned format stays the following one (with each row representing a sample) :

    - ['E' * n_soils, 'Phi' * n_soils, 'C' * n_soils, 'h' * n_soils] +
    - ['d' * n_struts, 'press' * n_struts] +
    - ['Exc', 'H', 'L', 'hw', 'load', 'EI', 'b']

    :return: {Numpy array}, shape(n_samples, n_features). The min values.
             {Numpy array}, shape(n_samples, n_features). The max values.
    """
    pass
```

Comment: post the code you have tried

Comment: Please do not post an image of code. Paste the actual code so that we can edit it. There's no way anyone will transcribe your code, unless they have nothing better to do.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You may find [this post useful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62545038) together [with this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29221551) seems to answer your question.